# Can't rvm pkg install zlib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, zlib

After I do

```
rvm uninstall 1.9.3
rvm pkg install zlib
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

there is still no zlib. Any gem install or gem update command fails with error:

```
$ gem update --system
ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::UpdateCommand
```

System is Ubuntu Server 11.10 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install the packages from the Ubuntu apt repos.

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev`

Remember to uninstall 1.9.3 again after you install these.

Comment: It worked. And, yeah, I had to reinstall 1.9.3 WITHOUT the --with-zlib-dir option.